# how to upgrade ubuntu tzdata 2023d to 2024a?

Tags: 22.04

### My Environment

- Ubuntu 22.04

### What I want to do

I want to upgrade ubuntu tzdata 2023d to 2024a.
(I'm trying to install edgedb and edgedb depends on it
(https://docs.edgedb.com/guides/deployment/bare_metal)

```
root@when2meet:~# apt-get install edgedb-4
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 edgedb-server-4 : Depends: tzdata (>= 2024a-0ubuntu0.22.04) but 2023d-0ubuntu0.22.04 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

### What I did

```
root@when2meet:~# sudo apt upgrade tzdata
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
tzdata is already the newest version (2023d-0ubuntu0.22.04).
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  eatmydata libeatmydata1 python-babel-localedata python3-babel python3-certifi python3-jinja2 python3-json-pointer python3-jsonpatch python3-jsonschema python3-markupsafe python3-pyrsistent
  python3-requests python3-tz python3-urllib3
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following packages have been kept back:
  linux-generic linux-headers-generic linux-image-generic
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 3 not upgraded.
```

```
root@when2meet:~# sudo apt list -a tzdata
Listing... Done
tzdata/jammy-updates,now 2023d-0ubuntu0.22.04 all [installed]
tzdata/jammy-security 2023c-0ubuntu0.22.04.0 all
tzdata/jammy 2022a-0ubuntu1 all
```

### The question

how do I upgrade the tzdata?

Comment: Did you run 'sudo apt update' first, to update your local repositories package-list ?

Comment: A Ubuntu 22.04 system should be using `tzdata | 2024a-0ubuntu0.22.04 | jammy-security  | source, all` so return to basics.. Run `sudo apt update` to update software lists & note any errors/warnings which need fixing before the next step, then ....

Comment: @guiverc It looks like a duplicate of another question but it isn't, and the proof that it isn't a duplicate is that I ran `apt policy tzdata` in Ubuntu 22.04 it said that tzdata 2024a was installed on my system. That means that tzdata 2024a was either installed automatically or it was upgraded from an earlier version.

Comment: @karel I don't know what the issue is, except it looks like the OP hasn't been upgrading packages very often. The `tzdata` they do have installed isn't the initial package provided with Ubuntu 22.04 LTS on release; nor is the version in *jammy-updates* (which is the identical package found in *jammy-security*) so I don't see the actual cause EXCEPT the user hasn't applied security fixes on their system very often (if at all; I didn't check what `tzdata` came on 22.04.1/22.04.2/22.04.3 media as I don't see much benefit with that; still show a non-updated system)

Comment: @guiverc The OP accepted my answer which closed the potential loopholes and commented "You SAVED MY LIFE! what a clear answer! it works like charm!"

Comment: The package was also found in *updates* too  (`tzdata | 2024a-0ubuntu0.22.04 | jammy-updates   | source, all`) so I wonder if they'd just not applied all upgrades.. but regardless that issue is solved.  Thanks for supporting end-users & the community as much as your do @karel

Comment: @guiverc If you ever need help with a similar problem with one of your questions or answers dm me in Raiders of the Lost Downboat chatroom and I'll try to help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

tzdata 2024a is provided by the jammy-security repository which provides security updates for Ubuntu 22.04. Before you run the next command you can try running `cat /etc/apt/sources.list` to check whether a line that says `deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy-security main restricted universe multiverse` already exists in your sources.list file.

In order to upgrade tzdata package to 2024a in Ubuntu 22.04 enable the jammy-security repository in `/etc/apt/sources.list` by running the following command.

```
sudo add-apt-repository "deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy-security main restricted universe multiverse"
```

This command does not add any new repositories for main, restricted, universe, or multiverse, but only adds the jammy-security repository.

After enabling the jammy-security repository, run the following commands to upgrade tzdata to 2024a:

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade
sudo apt install tzdata
```

Results of `apt policy tzdata` after running these commands:

```
tzdata:
  Installed: 2024a-0ubuntu0.22.04
  Candidate: 2024a-0ubuntu0.22.04
```

Comment: You SAVED MY LIFE! what a clear answer! it works like charm!